# c# - decimal to toString with pattern "#.##" doesn't properly format for a value of zero (0)

Tags: c#

The below code sets y = "" instead of "0.00". Is there a cleaner way to do the conversion for all decimals including 0 and have y properly set or is turnary operator setting variable z my best option?

```
        decimal x = 0;
        var y = x.ToString("#.##");
        var z = (x == 0) ? "0.00" : x.ToString("#.##");
```

Comment: `x.ToString("0.00");` should do it.  See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, you should replace the `#` with a `0`.

When using the "Digit placeholder" ("#"),

> ...no digit appears in the result string if the corresponding digit in the input string is a non-significant 0. For example, 0003 ("####") -> 3.

While the "Zero placeholder" ("0")

> replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.

<sub>(citations from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings))</sub>

So the correct way would be:

```
var y = x.ToString("0.00");
```